# expected output is not displaying

Tags: java, jax-rs, jersey-2.0

I am learing jersey,below is my program where the output should come like this 8-6-1990 but it is displaying 0-0-0.I dont know the actual reason,can anyone help me

### Multipleparam.java

```
package com.rest;

import javax.ws.rs.GET;
import javax.ws.rs.Path;
import javax.ws.rs.PathParam;
import javax.ws.rs.core.Response;

    @Path("multi")
    public class Multipleparam {
        @GET
        @Path("{day}/{month}/{year}")
        public Response getUserHistory(@PathParam("{day}") int day,
                @PathParam("{month}") int month, @PathParam("{year}") int year) {
            return Response.status(200).entity(day + "-" + month + "-" + year).build();
        }
    }
```

### web.xml

```
<web-app>
  <display-name>Archetype Created Web Application</display-name>
  <servlet>

        <servlet-name>Jersey REST Service</servlet-name>
        <servlet-class>com.sun.jersey.spi.container.servlet.ServletContainer</servlet-class>

        <init-param>
            <param-name>com.sun.jersey.config.property.packages</param-name>
            <param-value>com.rest</param-value>
        </init-param>

        <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>

    </servlet>

    <servlet-mapping>
        <servlet-name>Jersey REST Service</servlet-name>
        <url-pattern>/rest/*</url-pattern>
    </servlet-mapping>
</web-app>
```

I am passing this in browser `"http://localhost:9000/SingleParam/rest/multi/8/6/1990"`
I just want to know where is the mistake and why it is displaying zeros ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Pass pathparm parameter name without bracket.

```
package com.rest;

import javax.ws.rs.GET;
import javax.ws.rs.Path;
import javax.ws.rs.PathParam;
import javax.ws.rs.core.Response;

@Path("multi")
public class MultipleParam
{
    @GET
    @Path("{day}/{month}/{year}")
    public Response getUserHistory(@PathParam("day") int day, @PathParam("month") int month,
        @PathParam("year") int year)
    {
        return Response.status(200).entity(day + "-" + month + "-" + year).build();
    }
}
```