# Issue with JerseyClient webResource

Tags: java, jersey-client

Novice here. I have a REST service that looks like this:

```
@GET
@PATH("/{id}/headerinfo")
@Produces({ JSON, XML})
public Response getRequestHEADER(@PathParam("id") long id) {
    Request result = em.find(Request.class, id);

    ...

return Response.ok(entity).build();
```

here's my call to it, which is giving me problems:

```
@Path("") //what should go here?
public class AaRestCall
    public static String subTrackNum (String trackNum) throws IOException {
        try {
            Client client = Client.create();

            WebResource webResource = client.
            resource("https://url/rest/request/" +   trackNum);

            ClientResponse response = webResource.
            accept("application/json").get(ClientResponse.class);

            String output = response.getEntity(String.class);

            return output;
        }
        catch some stuff here

}
```

I have a few questions:

1) What goes in the @Path param?

2) webResource is giving me an error that it cannot be resolved when invoked as webResource.accept. I am unclear why.

3) Any additional tips would be appreciated, as this is my first REST call and first time using jersey.

Comment: Refer this for pathparam example : [http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24994599/expected-output-is-not-displaying/24994861#24994861](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24994599/expected-output-is-not-displaying/24994861#24994861)

Answer (score 1):

The path param that decorates a class would be the base uri for example `@Path("/")` then the methods inside the class would be path params for a specific uri after the / for example `@Path("test")`

Comment: So as I understand it, if the uri was www.google.com/somevariable, then the Path would be: @Path("www.google.com/")?

Answer (score 0):

Although it's old post, I would comment on some points.

> 1) What goes in the @Path param?

As far as I understood , below one is your server side, I meant service

> ```
> @GET
> @PATH("/{id}/headerinfo")
> @Produces({ JSON, XML})
> public Response getRequestHEADER(@PathParam("id") long id) {
>     Request result = em.find(Request.class, id);
>
>     ...
>
> return Response.ok(entity).build();
> ```

However 2nd one is your client side;

> ```
> @Path("") //what should go here?
> public class AaRestCall
>     public static String subTrackNum (String trackNum) throws IOException {
>         try {
>             Client client = Client.create();
>
>             WebResource webResource = client.
>             resource("https://url/rest/request/" +   trackNum);
>
>             ClientResponse response = webResource.
>             accept("application/json").get(ClientResponse.class);
>
>             String output = response.getEntity(String.class);
>
>             return output;
>         }
>         catch some stuff here
>
> }
> ```

Therefore you don't need to add

> Path("")

to your client class or function.Because with client request you're calling an API which has its' own pattern url such as **/service/list** therefore client consumes this service that means doesn't need any path unless you don't develop a kind of adapter which provide integration between 2 API.(it's a bit out of question concept, don't stick too much).

> 2) webResource is giving me an error that it cannot be resolved when
>   invoked as webResource.accept. I am unclear why.

Basically functionality of **webResource.accept(...)** add the accepted response media types such as json,xml,file etc. Therefore you should describe with more details for this.

> 3) Any additional tips would be appreciated, as this is my first REST
>   call and first time using jersey.

You can check one of the framework that is used for REST which is [Jersey](https://jersey.java.net/)